# Animate perspective of UIView to flip halfway up/away from bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I've got a view I'd like to flip like this illustration here.

[image]

My current solution:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                 animations:^{
                     [someView.layer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0)];
                 }];
```

The problem with this solution, is that the top edge is moving down, while the bottom edge is moving up. I want the top edge to stay and the bottom edge to be moving up/away like the illustration.

EDIT: It's like those cat doors, haha. You push a disc/squared surface away from you with hinges at the top.

EDIT2: The solution.

```
CGFloat someViewHeight = self.someView.frame.size.height;

CATransform3D baseTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
baseTransform.m34 = - 1.0 / 200.0;
self.someView.layer.zPosition = self.view.frame.size.height * 0.5;
self.someView.layer.transform = baseTransform;

CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(- M_PI_2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
CATransform3D firstTranslation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, someViewHeight * 0.5, 0.0);
CATransform3D secondTranslation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, - someViewHeight * 0.5, 0.0);

self.someView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DConcat(firstTranslation, CATransform3DConcat(rotation, secondTranslation)), baseTransform);
```

Took a while until I figured out that `[UIView animateWithDuration:]` will kind of animate the perspective or something, so the animation will shrink the view and do some weird stuff that I can't explain. So I now animate it my self, just changing the angle for each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
        [someView.layer setAffineTransform:
         CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, .0001f), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(.0f, someView.frame.size.height*-.5f))];
    }];
```

This is just fixing the issue you described, to get the result shown on your image you will require a 3D transformation.

To do a 3D transform things get quite tricky in your case:

```
    CGFloat viewHeight = someView.frame.size.height; //needed later as this value will change because of transformation applied
    CATransform3D baseTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(.0f, .0f, viewHeight*.5f); //put it towards user for rotation radius
    baseTransform.m34 = -1.0/200.0; //this will make the perspective effect
    someView.layer.zPosition = view.frame.size.height*.5f; //needed so the view isn't clipped
    someView.layer.transform = baseTransform; //set starting transform (no visual effect here)

    [UIView animateWithDuration:6.6 animations:^{
        someView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI_2, 1.0f, .0f, .0f), CATransform3DMakeTranslation(.0f, viewHeight*.5f, .0f)) , baseTransform);
      //or to stay at the same center simply:
      //someView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI_2, 1.0f, .0f, .0f) , baseTransform);
    }];
```

Now play around a bit with it.

Comment: I added the 3D transform example

Comment: Wow! Very nice, thanks! Almost exactly what I needed, I should be able to figure out the last part my self :) The top is moving, it should be still. But thanks a lot, very close ;)